# Calculus 2: Find Derivative of Problem Using Product Rule with Arcsin in Problem

Tags: calculus

I have the following math question:

[image]

I searched for solutions online but couldn't find any.  So I am wondering if my solution is correct.

[image]

Did I do this problem correctly? -- is my solution the right one?  If not, a step through would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: The answer is correct.

Comment: great! thank you :)